# how to have arrow symbol on a line in C#/WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am new to graphics in C#/WPF application.

I am having a WPF application and using Canvas for drawing various object at the runtime with the help of mouse. I am facing problem in drawing a line with arrow (like below):

(A) ------------>---- (B)

In this arrow sign should be at the 3rd part of the line (and should always point towards the moving mouse). For example if I click mouse at point "A" and move towards point "B" then arrow sign should point towards "B" as shown above.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Moon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for all your help and support. I have resolved my problem as below::

```
private static Shape DrawLinkArrow(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    GeometryGroup lineGroup = new GeometryGroup();
    double theta = Math.Atan2((p2.Y - p1.Y), (p2.X - p1.X)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
    Point p = new Point(p1.X + ((p2.X - p1.X) / 1.35), p1.Y + ((p2.Y - p1.Y) / 1.35));
    pathFigure.StartPoint = p;

    Point lpoint = new Point(p.X + 6, p.Y + 15);
    Point rpoint = new Point(p.X - 6, p.Y + 15);
    LineSegment seg1 = new LineSegment();
    seg1.Point = lpoint;
    pathFigure.Segments.Add(seg1);

    LineSegment seg2 = new LineSegment();
    seg2.Point = rpoint;
    pathFigure.Segments.Add(seg2);

    LineSegment seg3 = new LineSegment();
    seg3.Point = p;
    pathFigure.Segments.Add(seg3);

    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
    RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform();
    transform.Angle = theta + 90;
    transform.CenterX = p.X;
    transform.CenterY = p.Y;
    pathGeometry.Transform = transform;
    lineGroup.Children.Add(pathGeometry);

    LineGeometry connectorGeometry = new LineGeometry();
    connectorGeometry.StartPoint = p1;
    connectorGeometry.EndPoint = p2;
    lineGroup.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);
    System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
    path.Data = lineGroup;
    path.StrokeThickness = 2;
    path.Stroke = path.Fill = Brushes.Black;

    return path;
}
```

Thanks,

Moon

Comment: This answer helped me! For anyone wanting to have arrow at the end of the line, change 1.35 to 1. Thanks @Moon

Comment: @Moon, thanks! been searching around and this is the easily understandable and plug-and-play solution

Comment: Any idea how to make the arrow little curvy (arc style)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Canvas` control to represent the arrow,

```
<Canvas Margin="5" Width="60" Height="20">            
    <Line X1="10" Y1="10" X2="50" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" 
                  StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"/>
    <Line X1="35" Y1="10" X2="30" Y2="5" Stroke="Black" 
                  StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"/>
    <Line X1="35" Y1="10" X2="30" Y2="15" Stroke="Black" 
                  StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"/>
</Canvas>
```

If you want to create this at runtime, you can create the `Canvas` in the code behind class.

Note that the above sample, does not actually follow *arrow sign should be at the 3rd part of the line* rule, you may have to modify the coordinates of the line accordingly.

Comment: Hi Devendra, Thanks for your reply. The shape is right but I think I was not able to make my problem clear to you. The problem is that the canvas should be empty initially and when user click on the canvas and starts draging the mouse then this arrow image should pop-up on the screen and user can decide the length of the image at the runtime (means when he is dragging this image).

Comment: A long time ago, but if you only ever want one arrow, then I suggest binding something to Visibility. That would help you avoid managing another object.

Answer (score 2):

I just drew two with Expression Blend 4's arrow shapes which created this:

```
     <Window
        ...
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" ... /> 

    <ed:BlockArrow Height="8" Margin="119,181,169,0" Orientation="Left" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ed:LineArrow Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="1" Margin="119,117,169,0" Stroke="#FF027602" VerticalAlignment="Top" BendAmount="0" StartCorner="TopRight" StrokeThickness="2"/>
```

Comment: You need to provide an explanation for your down vote. This may not always be the most appropriate solution, but it is a valid option unless you can demonstrate otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use Path geometry. Have a look at this sample (maybe you already have) but it has similar requirements as yours, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using an image of the arrow you want. Make a quick photoshop .jpg or .png to use for the default arrow image and then just scale it based on the distance between points A and B. Rotation is a little more complicated, but if you've taken a basic trig course it should still be pretty easy.

The other way you could go about this is by drawing pixels. This is typically much more difficult, and the code for determining the direction of the arrow in this scenario is even more difficult. Again, I suggest the method above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't use the image option, b'coz I have to serialize this image into XML file and store it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.aspx) class to draw the line segments that compose your arrow. For example, you could draw one long line from A to B and two smaller, angled lines to draw the head pointing towards B.

The maths involved to find the appropriate line positions should not be too difficult. For the head, just settle on a size for the two segments and draw them near B angled by 30 degrees or so. Let me know if you have any issue.

The problem with the image technique is that the head will stretch with the length of the arrow. You would have to divide the bitmap between the head and the rest.